# ffmpeg converting PCM data file to wav file getting distorted(noisy) data

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, sox

I have raw pcm data in following form:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0100 0100 0000 0000 efbf bdef bfbd
0000 efbf bdef bfbd efbf bdef bfbd efbf
bdef bfbd efbf bdef bfbd efbf bdef bfbd
efbf bdef bfbd efbf bdef bfbd 0000 efbf
bdef bfbd 0000 efbf bdef bfbd efbf bdef
bfbd 2900 efbf bdef bfbd 0000 efbf bdef
bfbd efbf bdef bfbd efbf bdef bfbd 0000
```

and I want to make this data in wav file when I am converting by ffmpeg getting noisy data by this command:

```
sox -V -t raw -b 16 -e signed -r 16000 -c 1 14_32_7_187.pcm  new.wav
```

and:

```
ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 16000 -ac 1 -i 14_32_7_187.pcm -ar 16000 -ac 1 oout.wav
```

using both getting noisy data.

Comment: Did you _listen_ to the raw pcm data? It doesn't look random enough for "real" raw pcm audio.

Comment: yes I do, in raw it is also distorted. what that mean?

Comment: It means that your `.pcm` file is probably not a sound file at all, or a corupt one. `sox` and `ffmpeg` are not to blame here, and your invocations of them look OK to me (for raw 16-bit signed little-endian audio)

Comment: How do you know it is audio?

Comment: actually i am getting raw data of audio/x-wav;codec=pcm;bit=16;rate=16000 now I have to write this data in a .wav file, and I tried alot way to convert but I am getting distorted audio file.

Comment: can you share che original raw file?

Comment: You should post the original pcm file. `ef bf ed` is maybe not coincendentally the utf-8 encoding of the unicode replacement character U+FFFD. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29#Replacement_character

Comment: In terminal I am getting data in following form:-

\u0000\u0005\u0000��\u0001\u0000����������������������������������\u0003\u0000\u0004

so how can I convert this format to wav format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By executing this command we can convert raw/pca data to wav file.

ffmpeg -loglevel panic -f s16le -y -ar 16000 -ac 1 -i rawFile.pcm -ar 16000 -ac 1 output.wav

Answer (score 0):

By definition, because there is no format to conform to, any file can be considered valid raw data, be it audio or image. Whether it makes sense as an image or sound file is up to the listener or viewer, and cannot be decided by just looking at the raw data.

Your "raw pcm data" is probably not audio data at all, but it just *might* be the sound of two Martians making love, who knows?

`ffmpeg` and `sox` will happily convert any file from raw to `.wav`. If the resulting file sounds like random noise there are two possibilities:

- It is valid raw sound data, but you interpreted it incorrectly. For example: the samples are in big-endian format and you interpreted them as little-endian
- It is not raw sound data at all, but e.g. `.mp3` or even an executable. Raw sound files tend to be rather random (you'll almost never find the string "Happy Birthday" in them, but there still is a tiny chance you'll find those bytes in a recording of Mozart's Requiem)

Your file clearly falls in the second category. There are obvious repeating patterns (`efbf bdef bfbd`) you'll never find in real raw sound data (except perhaps in a Martian mating call)